# Why does the Realm Set object work at random?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

The function to use a `set` of Realm objects is always random.

Primary keys must not be changed and they must be unique.
So I added another variable for compare.
And I override isEqual(:) function.

See below my code.

```swift
class Model: Object {
    @objc dynamic var key = ""
    @objc dynamic var id = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "key"
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? Model {
            return id == object.id
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

let model1 = Model()
model1.key = UUID().uuidString
model1.id = "hi"

let model2 = Model()
model2.key = UUID().uuidString
model2.id = "hi"

let model1Array = [model1]
let model2Array = [model2]

let set1 = Set(model1Array)
let set2 = Set(model2Array)
```

```swift
let result = set1.intersection(set2)
print(result) // []
```

```swift
let result = set1.intersection(set2)
print(result) // [Model { key = 9E814B97-D0CC-4550-BF7B-19645C1DB746; id = hi; }]
```

```swift
let result = set1.intersection(set2)
print(result) // []
```

```swift
let result = set1.intersection(set2)
print(result) // []
```

```swift
let result = set1.intersection(set2)
print(result) // [Model { key = 8A399388-1FA2-4699-8258-5DA5DFCEC203; id = hi; }]
```

Every time I run, the values come out randomly.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe you should override `hash` as well.

Comment: @Sweeper Can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: `Set` uses the hash code of its objects. You should have an implementation of `hash` that is consistent with `isEqual`. i.e. If two objects are equal, they should have equal hashes. Try overriding `hash` to return `id.hash`. I am not 100% sure this will fix this it though.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you. But I don't understant that. Could you give me some code??

Comment: `override var hash: Int { return id.hash }`

Comment: @Sweeper Oh My God!! you save my day!!!! If you write answer, i select that. Thnak you very much!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Set` to work correctly, your objects need to have a correct implementation of `Hashable`. The Realm `Object` already implements `Hashable`, and presumably, the `==` implementation calls `isEqual`.

However, the `hash` should be consistent with `isEqual` as well, but you haven't overridden `hash` yet. You should implement `hash` such that two equal objects (as determined by `isEqual`) have equal hashes.

One way is to do it like this:

```
override var hash: Int {
    return id.hash
}
```